# Nuget Packages not available in TeamCity

Tags: octopus-deploy, teamcity-9.0, nuget-server

We are experimenting with using Octopus for CD using TeamCity.  We have enabled OctoPack to create the Nuget Packages for use during the deployment.  We also are experimenting with building libraries and using the integrated Nuget Server.

We were able to do both successfully.  Both deployment to an environment, and using Nuget.Config to both install the library package and restore and build in TC.

Yesterday, the CD stopped working, the packages are being built but the Nuget Server is not making them accessible.  We reset metadataBuilds, per TC instructions and we are still not getting new packages in the feed.  We did confirm that the packages are still being built.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would say a starting point to get a solution to this depends on where the nuget packages are stored when your solution is built in TC.

If they are left on the TC Nuget feed, then you would want to watch to see if there are more than 100 packages in the Nuget store (TC Artifacts). We have found that once you go over 100 packages, the ones after those 100 do not show up in the feed when Octopus tries to pull from it.

If you are pushing to the native Octopus Nuget store, perhaps watch to sere that the space on that server hasn't filled to the point where it cannot push any more of them.

The build log in TC should tell you a lot about where and how these packages are being dealt with. They should also show up as build artifacts after a build, which would allow further verification that they are at least being built.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be related, the Nuget feed in TC may take a while to pick up new packages after a build finishes. Particularly once you get a large number of packages. That may cause Octopus to fail if it is kicked off right afterwards (by a chained build).

What I've found works best is to push deployment packages directly to the Octopus internal nuget store, and keep shared (referenced in other projects) in TC or another nuget server. (NB you cannot use Octopus as a nuget server to retrieve packages). The push is done as an explicit step in the build that produces the packages.